# Scala - finding a specific tuple in a list

Tags: scala

Let's say we have this list of tuples:

```
val data = List(('a', List(1, 0)), ('b', List(1, 1)), ('c', List(0)))
```

The list has this signature:

```
List[(Char, List[Int])]
```

My task is to get the "List[Int]" element from a tuple inside "data" whose key is, for instance, letter "b". If I implement a method like "findIntList(data, 'b')", then I expect List(1, 1) as a result. I have tried the following approaches:

1. `data.foreach { elem => if (elem._1 == char) return elem._2 }`
2. `data.find(x=> x._1 == ch)`
3. `for (elem <- data) yield elem match {case (x, y: List[Bit]) => if (x == char) y}`
4. `for (x <- data) yield if (x._1 == char) x._2`

With all the approaches (except Approach 1, where I employ an explicit "return"), I get either a `List[Option]` or `List[Any]` and I don't know how to extract the "`List[Int]`" out of it.

Comment: If you have an `Option(char, List[Bit])`, such as what you get from `data.find`, you can get the actual tuple with `.get`: the caveat being that it will throw an exception if nothing was found.  For what it's worth, on this assignment I just wrote my own function as higher-order list functions are only introduced in Week 5.

Comment: (https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun)

Comment: Thanks Mark! The .get is the magic here

Comment: If you have an element of type "Option[T]" you can work on it through map/foreach/filter etc... This works as a quite nice abstraction over "null"

Comment: @mainas you should *accept* answers that solve your problem. Just click the checkmark next to the answer. If you don't accept answers on too many questions, people will stop answering your questions.

Comment: sorry, cant hold my emotions .... I agree... **scala is so lovable :)**

Answer (score 22):

One of many ways:

```
data.toMap.get('b').get
```

`toMap` converts a list of 2-tuples into a `Map` from the first element of the tuples to the second. `get` gives you the value for the given key and returns an `Option`, thus you need another `get` to actually get the list.

Or you can use:

```
data.find(_._1 == 'b').get._2
```

**Note**: Only use get on `Option` when you can guarantee that you'll have a `Some` and not a `None`. See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option for how to use Option idiomatic.

**Update: Explanation of the result types you see with your different approaches**

**Approach 2**: find returns an Option[List[Int]] because it can not guarantee that a matching element gets found.

**Approach 3**: here you basically do a `map`, i.e. you apply a function to each element of your collection. For the element you are looking for the function returns your List[Int] for all other elements it contains the value `()` which is the `Unit` value, roughly equivalent to `void` in Java, but an actual type. Since the only common super type of ´List[Int]´ and ´Unit´ is ´Any´ you get a ´List[Any]´  as the result.

**Approach 4** is basically the same as #3

Comment: Is it acceptable to use `get` on an unknown option when a NoSuchElementException would be the correct exception to throw?

Comment: @MarkPeters I would consider throwing that exception bad style (and certainly not idiomatic). So I guess if you implement some API that dictates this behaviour, and which you can't change it would be ok. Otherwise change the API to return an Option, or a  Try (http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.Try) or if you like Scalaz a Validation (http://blog.lunatech.com/2012/03/02/validation-scala)

Comment: data.find(_._1 == 'b').get._2 ------- I love genius! Thanks Jens. It works

Comment: Ok, I know I haven't researched thoroughly yet, so it's obvious I'm cutting corners here :-) . But I'm just wondering, with the several approaches I used, why do some give back List[Option] and other List[Any]?

Comment: @Jens: Agreed. The context here is an assignment on Huffman encoding, where the `List(Char, List[Bit])` is built up to include all of the characters you're trying to encode.  It would certainly be a programming/correctness error if the encoding table you just built up didn't include all of the characters in the string you're trying to encode.  But then something like an `AssertionFailedError` would probably be better.

Comment: @MarkPeters I agree. An exception would be ok in that case.

Comment: @mainas updated my answer to explain the return types you see.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is

```
data.toMap.apply('b')
```

Or with one intermediate step this is even nicer:

```
val m = data.toMap
m('b')
```

where `apply` is used implicitly, i.e., the last line is equivalent to

```
m.apply('b')
```

Comment: @thetrystero: I think this is due to `toMap` having an implicit argument.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing it. One more way:

```
scala> def listInt(ls:List[(Char, List[Int])],ch:Char) = ls filter (a => a._1 == ch) match {
 | case Nil => List[Int]()
 | case x ::xs => x._2
 | }
listInt: (ls: List[(Char, List[Int])], ch: Char)List[Int]
scala> listInt(data, 'b')
res66: List[Int] = List(1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like(when you are sure it exists) simply by adding type information.

```
val char = 'b'
data.collect{case (x,y:List[Int]) if x == char => y}.head
```

or use `headOption` if your not sure the character exists

```
data.collect{case (x,y:List[Int]) if x == char => y}.headOption
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this using pattern matching. Keep in mind you need to make it recursive though. The solution should look something like this;

```
def findTupleValue(tupleList: List[(Char, List[Int])], char: Char): List[Int] = tupleList match {
  case (k, list) :: _ if char == k => list
  case _ :: theRest => findTupleValue(theRest, char)
}
```

What this will do is walk your tuple list recursively. Check whether the head element matches your condition (the key you are looking for) and then returns it. Or continues with the remainder of the list.